# Why are the scalar variables undeclared inside cursor?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, procedure

I wrote a code snippet that is supposed to read a mapping table (`BcwmWDConfig`) and insert/update values of an outdated table (`Items`) in an old database (`BCWM99`) to a newer table in another database (`WebDET99.dbo.Items`).

I am getting errors that my supposedly declared (at least I thought so) variables are not declared.

```
DECLARE @v_bcwm_id INT = 0, 
        @v_wd_guid VARCHAR = '';

DECLARE bcwm_config_read_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT c.id, c.guid 
    FROM BcwmWDConfig c 
    WHERE c.guid IS NOT NULL;


PRINT '----READING CONFIG----';

OPEN bcwm_config_read_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM bcwm_config_read_cursor INTO @v_bcwm_id, @v_wd_guid

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT '----READ CONFIG FOR ID: '+@v_bcwm_id+' AS GUID '+@v_wd_guid+'----'
    PRINT '----INSERTING ITEMS WITH PARENT GUID: '+@v_wd_guid+'----'

    INSERT INTO WebDET99.dbo.Items
        SELECT 
            i.Id, i.Text, 
            CAST(@v_wd_guid AS VARCHAR(50)), 
            CAST(i.Linked_Feld AS VARCHAR(50)), 
            i.Linked_Item, i.Order
        FROM
            BCWM99.dbo.Items i
        WHERE 
            i.Parent_Feld = @v_bcwm_id

    PRINT '----INSERTED ITEMS WITH PARENT GUID: '+@v_wd_guid+'-----'

    FETCH NEXT FROM bcwm_config_read_cursor INTO @v_bcwm_id, @v_wd_guid
END

CLOSE bcwm_config_read_cursor;
DEALLOCATE bcwm_config_read_cursor;

SET @v_bcwm_id = 0, @v_wd_guid = '';

OPEN bcwm_config_read_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM bcwm_config_read_cursor
INTO @v_bcwm_id, @v_wd_guid

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT '----READ CONFIG FOR ID: '+@v_bcwm_id+' AS GUID '+@v_wd_guid+'----'
    PRINT '----UPDATING ITEMS WITH LINKED FIELD: '+@v_wd_guid+'----'
    UPDATE WebDET99.dbo.Items i
        SET i.Linked_Feld = @v_wd_guid
        WHERE i.Parent_Feld = CAST(@v_bcwm_id AS VARCHAR(50))
    PRINT '----UPDATED ITEMS WITH LINKED FIELD: '+@v_wd_guid+'-----'
    FETCH NEXT FROM bcwm_config_read_cursor
    INTO @v_bcwm_id, @v_wd_guid
END
CLOSE bcwm_config_read_cursor;
DEALLOCATE bcwm_config_read_cursor;

SET     @v_bcwm_id = 0, 
        @v_wd_guid = '';
```

Why are they undeclared inside the cursors? Also I am pretty sure I have some smaller syntax errors in my code, I am not used to SQL Server, maybe someone finds some other issues with this procedure.

Comment: Did you paste your cursor twice by mistake here in the question or is this how you actually are using it?

Comment: What is the error message. Quick notes, the update could be combined into the insert could it not, or if it is updating pre existing records, do them in the same cursor loop. Also when you print int variables you may need to cast these to vsrchars

Comment: Are you highlighting the whole text when executing

Comment: You should **never** declare a varchar variable without length. If a varchar variable is defined without length, it defaults to length of 1. Since you are apparently filling it with guid's, it won't fit.

Comment: @RigertaDemiri the inserts and updates are logically different as the rows containt both the parent id which I want to replace with the guid from the mapping table. When I insert the entries with (examplary) "parent field"-id "1" have an empty "linked field", and the rows with "parent field"-id 2,3,4... would have linked fields with either 1, 2 or 3. I can't update a non-existant entry, hence the double cursor.

Comment: @AbBennett (retranslated, original error is in German language): "SQL Error (137): The @v:bcwm_id-scalar variable has to be declared."

I did not highlight any part, I ran it as a whole

Thanks honey badger, didn't know that!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is sysntactically incorrect.

The first error: you cannot use `Order` (reserved word) without square brackets:

```
SELECT 
    i.Id, i.Text, 
    CAST(@v_wd_guid AS VARCHAR(50)), 
    CAST(i.Linked_Feld AS VARCHAR(50)), 
    i.Linked_Item, i.[Order] -----------------------------square brackets!
```

Second error:

```
SET @v_bcwm_id = 0, @v_wd_guid = '';
```

Should be:

```
SET @v_bcwm_id = 0; set @v_wd_guid = ''; ------------the same in the last row
```

The last error: get rid of "i":

```
UPDATE WebDET99.dbo.Items
SET Linked_Feld = @v_wd_guid
WHERE Parent_Feld = CAST(@v_bcwm_id AS VARCHAR(50))
```

Only then your code can be compiled.